# Unknown auth_key pusher laravel

Tags: laravel, pusher

[image]

I checked all of my pusher settings it may not seems wrong ,especially cluster. However, It keep giving me unknown auth_key , which i made sure already. Please enlighten me if i am wrong at somewhere. By the way , As for the info, i use laravel 4.2 though.Thanks in advance